# Want to convert the xml attribute structure to xml tag structure

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to convert the XML attribute structure to XML tag structure.for example

```
<company>
   <Name value="SomeCompany" /name>
   <Count value ="500"/>
</Company>
```

to

```
 <Company>
<Name>SomeCompany</name>
<EmployeeCount> 500<EmployyeCount>
</Company>
```

Here issue is input XML attribute structure is Dynamic.We don't know the exact schema of that.

I have tried to convert the input xml schema into json object(serializing) using Newtonsoft And able to convert the property names from count to Employe count.
But I am unable to convert the same json into xml tag structure(Deserializing).

```
 {     XmlDocument infodoc = new XmlDocument();
      infodoc.Load(@"C:\Users\dummy\desktop\test.xml");
             string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(infodoc);
             UpadtedXML h = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpadtedXML 
           (jsonText);
 }
```

Json is in this format:

```
{"Company":{"Name":{"@value":"someCompany"},"EmployeeCount":{"@value":"500"}
```

Expected result is like :

```
<Company>
<Name>SomeCompany</name>
<EmployeeCount> 500<EmployyeCount>
</Company>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work with any complex xml file.  I'm using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication124
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
               "<Company>\n" +
                  "<Name value=\"SomeCompany\"> </Name>\n" +
                  "<Count value =\"500\"/>\n" +
               "</Company>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            List<XElement> nodes = doc.Descendants().ToList();

            for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                XElement node = nodes[i];
                if ((string)node.Attribute("value") != null)
                {
                    node.ReplaceWith(new XElement(node.Name.LocalName, new object[] {
                        node.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "value"),
                        (string)node.Attribute("value"),
                        node.DescendantNodes()
                    }));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi All, How can I do the same operation in reverse. I have xml in the below format 
 
<Company>
<Name>SomeCompany</name>
<EmployeeCount> 500<EmployyeCount>
</Company> 

 and I want to convert that into       

<company>
   <Name value="SomeCompany" /name>
   <Count value ="500"/>
</Company>

Comment: Only the numbers?